# Don't show how to format code when I'm not on a programming site

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, code-formatting, sidebar

Instructions on how to format code are the first thing you see under "How to Format" when [asking a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), which is great, except when you're on a site that isn't about programming:

> ► create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~
>
> ````
> ```
> like so
> ```
> ````
>
> ► add language identifier to highlight code
>
> ````py
> ```python
> def function(foo):
>     print(foo)
> ```
> ````

Later on in the sidebar you're shown more instructions for code formatting:

> ► indent code by 4 spaces
>
> ► backtick escapes `` `like _so_` ``

Can these be removed, or at least moved down to the very bottom of the list on non-programming sites? [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) isn't for programming languages, so this needs to be fixed.

Maybe the rest of the list should be reordered too in order of importance (which would have link formatting coming somewhere closer to the top of the list).